# Ruby - Remove all other characters from a String

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string `h2#test- ruby is so awesome, blah, blah, blah`. I want to have `#test` to be the only characters left. is there a way in ruby to run a Regular Expression that removes all other characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.match(/(\#\w+)/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it as removing all other characters...think of it as capturing what you want.

```
'h2#test- ruby is so awesome, blah, blah, blah' =~ /(#test)/
your_captured_text = $1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str[/#[a-z]+/i]
```